# How to use scroll in an html div?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a command using divName.scroll in javascript and I want this command to scroll a scrollable html div but it is scrolling to the top and not to the desired element follows the code:

```
divName.scroll({
    top: elementName,
    behavior: "smooth"
})
```

Remembering that it is a scrollable div, inside a div with

```
display: block ;
```

inside a div

```
display: flex; 
position: fixed;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have any content in Div you can use overflow to get scroll option.

```
divName{display: flex; position: fixed;overflow: scroll;}
```

Comment: The scroll option is enabled, however the error is when I use the command that I showed in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you may have set your `top` to the name of another element, when it expects a number of pixels?

Try:

```js
divName.scroll({
    top: 100,
    behavior: "smooth"
})
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scroll seems to indicate a number should work.

Comment: I've tried to use it in pixels, but it's a problem when you decrease or increase the size of the browser, would you be able to use vw instead of pixel? Regarding the name of the element, I put it correctly but it continues to lead to the top, would that be an error in my code?